# Curl command in AFNetworking using Swift in Xcode 6

Tags: curl, swift, ios8, afnetworking, xcode6

I can currently hit an API with the following command in Terminal:

`curl -u me@website.com:ACCESS_TOKEN https://api.website.com/api/v1/ -D -`

How can I get a response with the same results using Swift and AFNetworking in Xcode 6?

How could I change the following code to implement my needs?

```
func searchInstagramByHashtag(searchString: String) {
    for subview in self.scrollView.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let instagramURLString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + searchString + "/media/recent?client_id=" + instagramClientID

    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    manager.GET( instagramURLString,
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

            if let dataArray = responseObject.valueForKey("data") as? [AnyObject] {
                self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, CGFloat(320*dataArray.count))
                for var i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++ {
                    let dataObject: AnyObject = dataArray[i]
                    if let imageURLString = dataObject.valueForKeyPath("images.standard_resolution.url") as? String {
                        println("image " + String(i) + " URL is " + imageURLString)

                        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(320*i), 320, 320))
                        self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
                            imageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageURLString))
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

If I am unable to use Swift and AFNetworking, what other approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first part of the url should work:

```
http://USER_NAME:ACCESS_TOKEN@api.instagram.com/...
```